# How to use StringBuilder in functional programming?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, stringbuilder

I was recently reading about functional programming. and I most say it comes with great benefits, but I have some performance concerns like when rendering a very big string like say an html page where I concatenate a lot of strings.
Normally I would use String builder. but I could not use it while still following functional programming paradigm.

**Poor Performance Code:** 
As you can see `ToListItem` and `ToUl` are pure functions

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static string ToListItem(string s)
        {
            return "<li>" + s + "</li>";
        }
        static string ToUl(string[] items)
        {
            return "<ul>" + String.Join("", items.Select(x => ToListItem(x))) + "</ul>";
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] items = new string[]
            {
               "Apple",
               "Orange",
               "Banana"
            };

            string htmlUl = ToUl(items);
            Console.WriteLine(htmlUl);

        }
    }
```

**Faster Code**
But as you can see `ToListItem` and `ToUl` are no longer pure functions and I could not come with a solution that make use of  `StringBuilder`  in pure functions

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void ToListItem(string s,StringBuilder sb)
        {
            sb.Append("<li>" + s + "</li>");
        }
        static void ToUl(string[] items, StringBuilder sb)
        {
            sb.Append("<ul>");

            foreach (var item in items)
                ToListItem(item, sb);

            sb.Append("</ul>");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] items = new string[]
            {
               "Apple",
               "Orange",
               "Banana"
            };

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            ToUl(items, sb);
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        }
    }
```

**So My Question Is:**

**Is It possible to use StringBuilder the functional programming way? How? and if not what is the alternative performance-wise solution?**

**Update1**
I included some examples. performance here do not matter but as the list grow linearly the Performance gap will grow exponentially.

Comment: I am not sure why you think `StringBuilder` cannot be used in Functional Paradigm style coding? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Pls add some code it will be easier to understand what problem do you have

Comment: @Fildor because when I call stringBuilder.Add I am changing the state of StringBuilder and when I have complex logic I need to have more than one function and To use string builder I normally have to pass it as a parameter.and call Add in the inner function which violates functional programming rules of pure function .

Comment: @DiaaEddin This depends a lot on what the `StringBuilder` is used for. But if you absolutely don't want to pass it on, just make the called functions build and return strings to add to a `StringBuilder` in the main function.

Comment: `.Append` (there is no Add) returns the reference to the builder, so there is no any paradigm violation.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy I am pretty sure it modifies the original `StringBuilder` instance and returns a reference to it.

Comment: So, the question is "am I allowed to use object references as parameters in FP?" The answer is "no".

Comment: It seems to me that you've come across the concept of FP and are now trying to shoehorn it in everywhere. Please don't do that. If you want to use pure FP, do so in an FP language like F#, otherwise accept that trying to use pure FP in an OOP language like C# is always going to be a compromise.

Comment: @IanKemp I Know that at some point I need to do side effects like I/O operations and that`s okay. but I need to have as much code as possible to be functional so it has more expected behavior and easier to test. So my question is is it possible to move a code like this to the functional part without compromising performance.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy So you are saying that I am not allowed to use StringBuilder in FP?

Comment: _"...ToUl are pure functions"_ -- I'm not sure I even agree with that. I guess technically `ToUI()` is purely functional. But only because you delegated the iterative work to a different method. It's not really all that clear here what your exact requirement is, nor what specific trouble you're having meeting that requirement.

Comment: For that matter, I don't even see how the "non-functional" `ToUI()` would be appreciably faster than the "functional" example. The latter uses `string.Join()`, which internally is going to use a reasonable string concatenation algorithm. There is some very small overhead for the LINQ-style expressions, but nothing that should break the bank.

Comment: @PeterDuniho you are absolutely right. in this very example String.join will perform as good as String builder. I did not know it was optimized this way until I tested it with heavy data. anyways my point stands still in general StringBuilder will out perform  any other method to build long strings especially in a recursive implementation.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I was wondering if there is a convenient way to pass StringBuilder instance to build large strings. but I guess it is not possible after all. I think I need to give up FP concepts to unleash the true power of StringBuilder

Comment: _"is a convenient way to pass StringBuilder instance to build large strings"_ -- your goals remain unclear. You can of course write a recursive method that takes as a parameter a `StringBuilder` instance, for example the purpose of building large strings. A good compiler may even optimize the tail recursion into a non-recursive function. `StringBuilder` and FP aren't mutually exclusive. But why is FP a goal in the first place here? Why jump through all these hoops? What _benefit_ do you hope to achieve?

Comment: Hope my answer can give you satisfaction to what you wanna achieve

Comment: Functional Programming has a number of benefits. As a simple example, it's slightly easier to unit test the individual functions in the first program than the second. The code is also simpler. There _are_ cases where FP just isn't a good fit. In this case, though, it's probably more that C# itself isn't a good fit, as HTML should be built in a templating language intended for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

This does not address the case above exactly, but it provides a baseline on which you could build something for your case, with header and footer parameters.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

public static class FunctionalStringBuilder
{
    public static string BuildString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, string> response)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            builder.Append(response(item));
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
    var list = new List<Employee>
    {
        AutoFaker.Generate<Employee>(),
        AutoFaker.Generate<Employee>(),
        AutoFaker.Generate<Employee>(),
        AutoFaker.Generate<Employee>()
    };
    var result = list.BuildString(
                    e => $"Employee Id: {e.Id}, Name: {e.Name}, DateOfBirth: {e.DateOfBirth}\n");
```

Comment: Interesting solution.. but it is not complete . what if the tree is very deep. then at some point I will be calling BuildString recursively and passing strings around. the strings will get longer and performance will drop. I was looking for a way to pass String Builder to multi functions with respect to FP. but I guess it is not possible after all :/

Comment: @DiaaEddin Good point. I saw that possibility.  However, just because a method can be called recursively doesn't mean that you should.

Comment: @DiaaEddin Not sure you have these tools available to you, but it occurred to me that it is unlikely StringBuilder is the correct solution for your case.  If you can, build a type that can be serialized to markup as a tree.

Comment: It should be noted that `String.Join` is effectively implemented in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I would challenge your assumption that StringBuilder has significantly better performance. Before you start throwing tomatoes, please hear me out.

We've had it drilled into our heads that you never, ever do this:

```
var s = "<ul>";
foreach(var item in items)
{
  s += $"<li>item</li>";
}
s += "</ul>";
```

That pattern is dangerous, because if you have a large number of items (`n`) then you end up creating `n` new strings, and each time you are copying the previous string into the new string, and as the length grows proportionately to `n`, meaning you're doing roughly `n²` work. This doesn't scale well.

But this is an entirely different story:

```
var s = $"<ul>{string.Concat(items.Select(i => $"<li>{i}</li>"))}</ul>";
```

`String.Concat` very efficiently figures out how long the final string needs to be and constructs a single string, copying all the values into the right places in that string.

Now, it's true that this is creating `n` strings (via the `Select`), but the sum of the lengths of all those strings is proportionate to `n`. So creating the strings and copying all those strings into a final string is ~`2*n` work, which in the vast majority of cases you will never actually notice. You've probably spent more time reading this answer than your program will ever spend executing this code in a lifetime of real-world use. In terms of algorithmic complexity, it's `O(n)`, which is the same as if you'd used a StringBuilder.

According to [my LINQPad tests](https://share.linqpad.net/94n2ifmf.linq), your Join code only takes ~50% longer than your StringBuilder code. This falls squarely in the realm of premature optimization. Your application will spend *orders of magnitude* more time sending this HTML to your user's browser than it will spend building this string.

Focusing on the StringBuilder question may be distracting you from a much more important question, though: why are you using C# code to build HTML in the first place? There are templating languages like Razor that are not only designed to solve this problem efficiently, but which provide protection against problems like script injection.

Is there a possibility that, at some point, the values in `items` will be provided by a user? If so, those users could enter `<script>/*malicious code*/</script>`, and use it to do all kinds of nasty things when other users see the list items they entered. That's what you really need to be worried about.

Answer (score -1):

From my opinion you can build it to be like this

```
package org.example;

import java.util.Optional;

public class StringBuilderFunctionalMain {

  static StringBuilder addListItems(String[] items, StringBuilder sb, int index) {
    if (index >= items.length) {
      return sb;
    }

    return addListItems(items, sb.append("<li>").append(items[index]).append("</li>"), index + 1);
  }

  static StringBuilder toUl(String[] items, StringBuilder sb) {
    return Optional.of(sb)
        .map(stringBuilder -> stringBuilder.append("<ul>"))
        .map(stringBuilder -> addListItems(items, sb, 0))
        .map(stringBuilder -> stringBuilder.append("</ul>"))
        .get();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] items = new String[]
        {
            "Apple",
            "Orange",
            "Banana"
        };
    Optional.of(new StringBuilder())
        .map(sb -> toUl(items, sb))
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Comment: "To achieve a functional programming you need return value of a function to be continued as next function" - No, that's not true. You're describing a continuation and that could be in an imperative language too.

Comment: Wikipedia says this: In computer science, functional programming is a programming paradigm where programs are constructed by applying and composing functions. It is a declarative programming paradigm in which function definitions are trees of expressions that map values to other values, rather than a sequence of imperative statements which update the running state of the program.